# Which areas of maths should underperforming western countries focus on?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, exams, assessment

I am not sure which StackExchange to ask this question but I am interested in the relative underperformance of Western countries such as Australia, US, UK compared to other higher performing countries in the world. More specifically whether there are specific areas of mathematics of underperformance that have been discussed or highlighted before.

The PISA testing results that I have found online are very broad and generic but does not break down into the usual specific areas of maths for example, like [this report from the OECD.](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/docserver/9789264266490-9-en.pdf?expires=1615355002&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=7680A40DC65D2E99DBFCF7587658EC5C)

I am aware that another test TIMSS is problematic when comparing the ["West" versus the rest](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21728985-800-west-vs-asia-education-rankings-are-misleading/) but I wonder if there are specific subjects areas that are linked to underperformance rather than a general pedagogical approach issue.

Comment: Mathematics in primary education or on more advanced level?

Comment: These international testing is across the primary and high school spectrum for the most part. But I know there are tentative changes in some of the trends so it is a gross overgeneralisation but if I wonder if there is any drill down analysis or commentary of subject areas of underperformance

Comment: Personally, I think it's less a problem of pedagogy and more a problem of how individuals view education. I'd be interested in survey's which probe into how education is viewed in countries where it is not automatic that everyone can go to school and college.

Comment: Also there are different emphasis on education for example conceptual understanding versus rote memorisation or repetition usually embedded into the standards or accreditation processes too - https://uwaterloo.ca/chem13-news-magazine/november-2014/recommended/why-educational-research-matters-you-rote-vs-meaningful

Comment: Concerning the US it pays to note that Massachusetts has a PISA score inline with Korea, Finland, etc. Given that states like Idaho have teacher shortages, arguably the US scores are lower than expected due to factors not related to the teaching per se.

Comment: Yes, SES issues especially a shortage of maths and science teachers create a vicious cycle for those who need it most https://educationhq.com/news/making-up-the-numbers-in-maths-teacher-drought-80234/

Comment: In Australia there is political pressure to improve this but I haven't seen an improved strategy unfortunately https://theconversation.com/fixing-the-shortage-of-specialist-science-and-maths-teachers-will-be-hard-not-impossible-99651

Comment: In this article Gavin argues that "Measurement and geometry are areas of particular concern. U.S. student performance has been consistently low in these areas and at times has been the lowest among all participating countries (Mullis et al., 2004; Gonzales
et al., 2008)" - https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5951/jresematheduc.44.3.0478

Comment: It starts with learning to read taking three years or longer instead of being done in half a year. Then crappy texbooks or no texbooks. Programs that every teacher creates herself instead of following a national curricula. It all adds up, watered down algebra starts in 9th grade instead of 7th, physics and chemistry are one year optional in HS instead of MS, etc. Don't know about other Western countries, but what is taught in American schools (not taking into account AP classes) [can easily fit in 8-9 years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8-bkA_V-B8).

Comment: Good point. If there are an array of excellent national resources and materials, then the curricula can be taught much more in-depth and quicker.

Comment: I agree with @Poidah, although my evidence is only anecdotal. I remember a high school math teacher as well as a college professor mentioning to me that the US struggles with geometry when compared to other countries. When I first heard this, I thought "but I did fine in geometry, surely I would do ok in a geometry class in another country." It wasn't until I took a *college* class on Euclidean +Non Euclidean geometry that I realized how much "basic high school" geometry I did not know (four centers of a triangle, inscribed angle theorem, power of a point, etc).

Comment: If your question is what should be done for countries to score better on international standardized tests, I would counter by asking why.  As Campbell's editorial lays out, there hasn't been a correlation shown between PISA scores and future economic health, much less a causation.  As an American high school teacher, I couldn't tell you why we rank below most nations and some species of dogs on these tests, but after failing to predict the death of our economic standing for over 50 years I also don't know why I should care.

Comment: The problem is worsening disparity compounded by maths underperformance contributing to widening inequality in disadvantaged groups in those "Western" countries - https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/2018/apr/england-behind-other-countries-maths-performance-disadvantaged-pupils

Comment: @MatthewDaly "after failing to predict the death of our economic standing for over 50 years I also don't know why I should care" — I agree that an average person should do well with some algebra, some geometry and basic trig. But then school should be reduced from 13 years (including K) to 9 or 10 years at most.

Comment: Economic standing for who? Poor maths instruction contributes to the widening gap between the have and have nots. Education is only entrenching poverty rather than lifting people out of it and minimising maths instruction contributes to this - https://research.msu.edu/schools-worsen-inequality-especially-in-math/